# Can codeforces problem 455D be solved using Deque+Sqrt Decomposition?

Tags: c++

So the task is this: you are given an array Arr of size n. the elements of the array range from 1 to n. you have two types of queries:

1. (l, r) -  do a cyclic shift in the subarray Arr[l, r] both ends inclusive.
2. (l, r, k) - print out the number of elements in the range [l, r], that are equal to k;

Link to the original problem: https://codeforces.com/contest/455/problem/D

I decided to do this:
let's divide the array Arr into sqrt(n) blocks.
let's store sqrt(n) deques(C++ STL deque).
also let's store sqrt(n) counter arrays where cnt[i][j] is the number of times the number j occurs in the i-th block

the first query can be done in O(sqrt(n)) time, if we just update the deque of the corresponding blocks using pop_back and push_front as well as update the counter arrays.

The second query can be done by just calculating the sum cnt[i][k] over the corresponding blocks i.

I'm getting WA4 implementing this idea, I can't find the bug in my code so it got me thinking maybe the idea is wrong. What do you think?

this is my submission

```
int n;

void decode(int &l, int &r, int lastans) {
    l = ((l + lastans - 1) % n);
    r = ((r + lastans - 1) % n);
    if (l > r)
        swap(l, r);
}

void decode(int &l, int &r, int &k, int lastans) {
    decode(l, r, lastans);
    k = ((k + lastans - 1) % n)+1;

}

int main() {
    ios::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0); cout.tie(0);

    cin >> n; 

    vector<int> a(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> a[i];

    int sqt = sqrt(n + .2) + 1;
    vector<deque<int> > b(sqt);
    vector<vector<int> > cnt(sqt, vector<int> (n+1));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int blok = i / sqt;

        b[blok].push_back(a[i]);
        cnt[blok][a[i]]++;
    }

    int q;
    cin >> q; 
    int lastans = 0;

    while (q--) {
        int l, r, k, t;
        cin >> t;

        if (t == 1) {
            cin >> l >> r; 
            decode(l, r, lastans);

            int b1, b2;
            b1 = l / sqt;
            b2 = r / sqt;

            if (b1 == b2) {
                int temp = b[b2][r%sqt];

                for (int g = r % sqt; g > l%sqt; g--) {
                    b[b2][g] = b[b2][g - 1];
                }
                b[b1][l%sqt] = temp;
            }
            else {
                int temp = b[b2][r%sqt];
                cnt[b2][temp]--;

                for (int g = r % sqt; g > 0; g--) {
                    b[b2][g] = b[b2][g - 1];
                }
                cnt[b2][b[b2].front()]--;
                b[b2][0] = b[b2 - 1].back();
                cnt[b2][b[b2].front()]++;

                for (int g = b2 - 1; g > b1; g--) {
                    cnt[g][b[g].back()]--;
                    b[g].pop_back();
                    b[g].push_front(b[g - 1].back());
                    cnt[g][b[g].front()]++;
                }
                cnt[b1][b[b1].back()]--;

                for (int g = (int)b[b1].size()-1; g > l%sqt; g--) {
                    b[b1][g] = b[b1][g - 1];
                }
                b[b1][l%sqt] = temp;
                cnt[b1][temp]++;
            }
        }
        else {
            cin >> l >> r >> k; 
            decode(l, r, k, lastans);

            int b1 = l / sqt;
            int b2 = r / sqt;

            if (b1 == b2) {
                int ans = 0;

                for (int g = l % sqt; g <= r % sqt; g++) {
                    ans += b[b1][g] == k ? 1 : 0;
                }

                lastans = ans;
                cout << lastans << '\n';
            }
            else {
                int ans = 0;
                for (int g = l % sqt; g < b[b1].size(); g++) {
                    ans += b[b1][g] == k ? 1 : 0;
                }
                for (int g = b1 + 1; g < b2; g++) {
                    ans += cnt[g][k];
                }
                for (int g = 0; g <= r % sqt; g++)
                    ans += b[b2][g] == k ? 1 : 0;
                lastans = ans;

                cout << lastans << '\n';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include all your code (and any other relevant information) in the question itself. The third-party website may not keep it around for long and then this question is not going to make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: You did pass the first three test cases and the first 19 lines of the fourth test case, so your approach is probably mostly correct. It shows you the test data, so you can step through your code with a debugger to find the bug.

Comment: @jakub_d done. I have included my code.

Comment: @Brian I can't debug because the test data isn't complete. There are not up to 20 queries of the second type in the test data.